# Making hidden field visible when another field is used

Tags: django

I am trying to create a section in my models code that allows me to add a value only when the previous field is selected.

The goal of the code is to do the following

1. Have a null or blank option
2. Select an option from the tuple
3. Showing the new field option

The example of what I am looking to do is add a warranty to an item in my model. I am trying to make a date field (or a charfield that uses a date format) that only appears when an option is selected (i.e. a date field is available when the 30 day warranty is selected) otherwise the date field should be hidden (i.e. none is selected, so date field does not show)

Any suggestions, workarounds are welcomed
This is in Django Admin only

Comment: First use javascript to capture the select/unselect event, then show/hide the field you want to show/hide. Without javascript you couldn't do that.

Comment: There must be a way to use to do it without JS. I am looking to use tuples which allows a default option. I want the date field be visible when another option besides the default is selected.

Comment: There's no way for your to show/hide a dom element without refreshing the page if you are not using javascript. If you think refreshing the page doesn't matter it's a different story.

Comment: I am using django for my code. This is not visible to anyone (not using html for this part) as it is strictly in django admin. There is no Dom elements at play.